# Sending and Queuing emails in laravel

Tags: email, queue, laravel-5

Hello i am trying to send emails in laravel this is currently what i do:

```
$parameters = array(
    'date_of_purchase' => date('l, d m Y H:i A'),
    'amount' => $amount,
);

// Sending Mail
Mail::queue('emails.bus-ticket-purchase', $parameters, function ($message) use ($customer_email) {
    if ($message->to($customer_email, '')->subject('Ticket Purchase')) {
        $all_good = true;
    }
});
```

This works fine,all emails get delivered, but i started getting complaints about how some emails were taking about an hour to come through so i decided to read laravels documentation on emails and queues, what i found there was actually quite different from what i had done:

[Laravel Mail Queues](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues)

So i run the artisan command to create the SendMail command and tried to folow the rest of the documentation but i still do not get it, it states that to send a mail(push it on a queue) i should do this:

```
Queue::push(new SendEmail($message));
```

Now where does the above code go? In my SendMail command or in my controller? Is there somewhere where i can see how this all works, i would really like someone to explain all this to me.